# Angular 2 audio won't break by changing component

Tags: angular, typescript, audio

I want to play audio with help of this code and it works fine

```
  ngOnInit () {
    const a = new Audio();
    a.src = '../../assets/hello.wav';
    a.load();
    // auto-start
    a.play();
  }
```

But when I click Next Button, that leads me to next page ( so I change my component with help of routing) the audio will not stop (will not break) and the music from audio plays on the next page also. What should I add to my code to make it possible by changing page break the audio?

Comment: You could hook into the router's navigation events, or look at the other lifecycle events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you shall define `audio` as a field of your component(in order to access it at ngOnDestroy) and destroy it at `ngOnDestroy`.

```
audio: any;

ngOnInit () {
  this.audio = new Audio();
  this.audio.src = '../../assets/hello.wav';
  this.audio.load();
  // auto-start
  this.audio.play();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  // destroy audio here
  if(this.audio) {
    this.audio.pause();
    this.audio = null;
  }
}
```